# Incomplete answers converge to nearly identical acceptable ones

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

The scenario is that two answers (or more) are posted on the same question, both with some distinct flaws.

**Answer 1**, posted first, was posted without any explanation, just code that was ok but not perfect/ideal.

**Answer 2** was posted with explanations, but minor flaws in code too.

At first I gave suggestions to answer 2 in comments to fix the code since it had an explanation (even if code was somewhat similar to Answer 1's) and felt more complete and adequate. However, other users have commented the first answer at nearly the same time and now both are converging to an identical, correct answer.

Now I kind of have this dilemma: should I upvote the second answer which was posted after suggestions were made to the first one, or suggest the first answer to add explanations ?

---

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373394/assign-new-value-to-a-string-index/51373634) question for reference (with answers from `un-lucky` and `Hoppeduppeanut`).

Comment: Is the explanation added to answer 1 noticably different from answer 2? Or does it seem like code-only answer, just prosthetically augmented by a non-original explanation? In the worst case copying from answer 2....

Comment: to be honest i'd downvote un-lucky's answer because it doesn't explain anything about the code it's posted as an answer. what was the cause of the problem? how does the code fix it? there's 2 other answers which are the same kind of code dump answers which i hate because they are only useful to  the Asker and people with the exact same code as the asker, **not useful** to those who have the same or similar problem but different code

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the events went like this: 1 had an answer with `elseif` chain, was suggested to use `switch/case`, 2 was posted with with non-compilable code but with `switch/case` and explanation (which needs slight correction).
@Memor-X So you're saying it would be preferable to downvote at this point or anytime there's an answer without explanations ? I would tend to comment first, but that led me to this situation where I just can't suggest answer to to improve. I guess downvote is my only option...

Comment: @Mat votes are opinions and it's just my opinion to downvote any answer which doesn't explain it's code (ie. *"try this [code dump]"* answers). if i am feeling in the mood i'd leave a comment but really i feel that answerers should be aware that people other than the asker are going to be seeing the post so should know to explain their code

Comment: Fair enough, I would agree. I think the question still applies though because personally it's not the first time I see it; if different salvageable answers converge (or seem to converge) to the same good answer, should one be deleted ?

Comment: The other thing that's worth noting is that the correct path may be to just let stuff stand for a few minutes more.  I have the accepted answer to that question.  I posted clear code and some explanations, but deliberately left some things for the student to look up.  When I started whipping up my code, there was one answer to the question posted (and, if I remember correctly, it hadn't been there very long).  By the time I finished, the other answer discussed here had appeared.  All three probably came in the first hour after the initial post.

Comment: Isn't this a First World Problem? I see nothing wrong with having multiple good answers; and indeed I regularly upvote multiple answers on the same question: if an answer looks good, I upvote it on its own merit.

Comment: @Matt Can you give an example of a question raised on Meta that isn't? I imagine "How can I end world poverty?" would be closed as off-topic.

Comment: If you believe in an 'absolute truth' then there is of course 1 optimal answer to each question that is written in an optimal way for all readers to understand. So, assuming all editors are working towards the best possible answer written in the best way possible, then, as time approaches infinity **all** answers converge into identical ones. I'm not sure how this should affect your votes though.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland: I was using "First World Problem" figuratively. The OP is basically asking about what to do when a question has two (or more) good answers, while many questions either have passable, terrible or no answer at all. I find it amusing :)

Comment: @Matt that is false. The question was about 2 incomplete different answers (i.e. not good enough to upvote imo) converging to the same good answer after suggested changes to both.

Comment: @Mat: *Now I kind of have this dilemma: should I upvote the second answer which was posted after suggestions were made to the first one, or suggest the first answer to add explanations ?* => From I see here, the meat of the question is what to do once both answers are good. Does it really matter how they ended up being good (as long as no plagiarism occurred)?

Comment: @Matt yes that is correct, but the subtle point was that both answers would converge to a nearly identical one. However, like jpp said, once explanations are properly added to the answers, it should be very rare that they are identical, in which case yes it could be correct to upvote both. I hope this clarifies my initial thoughts a bit.

Comment: @Mat: Sure; once they have converged to both being good, we have a First World Problem though, which I found fun. Good fun of course; there are so many depressing cases of poor answers being brought to meta, it's nice to see good answers from time to time :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Let the multiple answers stand. The value-add isn't code, it's code + explanation. It's **very** rare for all answers to share identically worded explanations.

You may upvote the one(s) you think best explain the problem & solution. Perhaps, over time, those will rise to the top and help future visitors.

Some responders may choose to delete their answers, but this is neither required nor necessarily desirable. Often different explanations of the same problem / solution add insight.

Comment: Your answer and Memor-X's comments both made much sense to me. Next time I will stick with suggesting fixes to the best initial answer.

Comment: @Mat if you have the time, it's still best to suggest fixes to all answers.

Comment: Or just implement the fix.

Comment: `Often different explanations of the same problem / solution add insight.` I guess that's why, once an answer is accepted, SO doesn't hide/delete the other ones :)

Comment: I disagree that one should only upvote the "best" one. If there are multiple good answers, I see nothing wrong in upvoting both.

Comment: @MatthieuM., Sure, I guess you can't ask a dozen people on how they vote and they'll each come up with a different answer. I like my votes to **differentiate** questions/answers. If there are 2 great but different explanations, I *might* upvote both. But *typically* there's one that makes most sense to me and I'll upvote that one.

Comment: @jpp: Oh, I was not criticizing *your* way of voting, so much as I was criticizing how you instructed the OP to vote. There is no SO guidance that I know of here, so I think your answer could be improved by making it clear that "upvote the best" is *your* personal preference, and not a community guideline.

Comment: @MatthieuM., Fair point, I've updated the wording.

Comment: "It's **very** rare for all answers to share identically worded explanations" - I'd say it's more than that, I challange anyone to find such an example! (Preferably a legit example where 2 answers have converged, not just a copypasta)